# How change Magento2 config cache behavior

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, cache, core-config-data

In my project with 100's of websites in multi-store mode, several seconds on every request are used to **unserialize** the config cache.

It appears that Magento builds and compiles the config-cache from all config scopes on initial load and includes all store scopes into that.

Does anyone have experience in changing the config loader in such a way that it would only compile the config for a given store (the one currently being requested) and caching that set individually.

This would permit invalidating config caches for a specific store as well drastically cut back on unserialization of configs that aren't even part of the request.

Answer (score 0):

I may have a simple solution. At least, the concept below is quite simple:

1. change the place where store specific config data are stored so that they are separate from the current config. To do this, write an around plugin for the function
   `\Magento\Config\Model\Config::save`
2. clear all the store config data in one script. I would look at customising the command `php bin/magento app:config:dump` but can't tell right now if it would be sufficient.
3. test/verify the unserialize happens faster than previously and double checking only the global remain
4. change the function that reads the config data: `\Magento\Framework\App\Config::getValue`. For instance if scopeCode is set, then a customised model saves the data in another cache.